# String not valid on line breaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

Im added a string value in my JSON embedding ruby code, but in browser not receive a string behavior between quotation marks.

[image]

I was trying catch the break line *'\n'* and replace with nothing, or with javascript breakline

```
"description": "<%= p.description.gsub('\n', '%0A') %>",
```

Another option was..

```
"description": "<%= p.description.delete!("\n").html_safe %>",
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a "\n" in the description string? From what you posted I don't see any.

Comment: there are \r\n in the string. So `.gsub("\r\n", "")` goes fine. Thanks

Comment: after `amortiguacion` your text changed color, looks like there some syntax error, make sure that there in text everything ok and all your text this one string. I think it should help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [String#squish](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-squish) provided by ActiveSupport.

> ### squish()
>
> Returns the string, first removing all whitespace on both ends of the string, and then changing remaining consecutive whitespace groups
>   into one space each.
>
> Note that it handles both ASCII and Unicode whitespace.
>
> ```
> %{ Multi-line
>    string }.squish                   # => "Multi-line string"
> " foo   bar    \n   \t   boo".squish # => "foo bar boo"
> ```

Comment: Note that if this is a used provided string you may still want to strip or escape any HTML tags to avoid potential XSS attacks.